# Playerprefs not displaying when the value is 0?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a *playerprefs* setup, if the user has **not** played the number is automatically set to `0`.  This is so it can load the **first** image in the table.

Although **no** image is displayed, the title does **not** change to `0`, and **nothing** is displayed in the console.

If I set the default value to `1` **all of the above immediately work**.

Does anybody know why this is?

```
 public void onClick()
    {
        PurchaseConfirmation.SetActive(true);

        var Tier = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Freeze_Tier", 0);
        int[] Tiers_Prices = {100, 250, 500, 1000, 2500, 5000, 1000, 5000, 10000, 20000};
        Sprite[] TierList = {Tier1, Tier2, Tier3, Tier4, Tier5, Tier6, Tier7, Tier8, Tier9, Tier10};

        Title.text = "Freeze";
        Stats.text = "+ 1 Second Frozen";
        Price.text = "$" + Tiers_Prices[Tier].ToString();
        Title.text = Tier.ToString();
        Debug.Log(Tier);
        Tiers.sprite = TierList[Tier];
        Purchase.sprite = TierList[Tier];
    }
```

Comment: Tier1, Tier2 etc are sprites btw

Comment: Please show where and how `Tier1` is defined and assigned.  _"Tier1, Tier2 etc are sprites btw"_ doesn't really count.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `Tier1` texture set to anything? Have you tried setting the `Tier2` texture to `Tier1` and reverse? Maybe it's something with the sprite not displaying properly. The rest of the code looks fine to me, altho I'd suggest you go by the naming conventions to make it easier to read

[C# Naming Conventions](https://github.com/ktaranov/naming-convention/blob/master/C%23%20Coding%20Standards%20and%20Naming%20Conventions.md)

Comment: yea the images are all good, but it still isn't displaying

Comment: actually I fixed it, it was because my playerprefs had already gone past the limit because I'd used that device before, I just cleared them.